# Add Bookmark/Favorite with javascript (no JQuery)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am searching for a solution without JQuery to add a bookmark / favorite at a button click, in a VueJS website (and we don't have jquery plugged in)

I can't find anything !

I have tested .addPannel for firefox and it prompts an error, and addFavorite for IE with same result. It says that the method does not exists.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Modern browsers do not provide an API to trigger bookmarking from JavaScript.